# Is there a way to create a new row and add certain elements to that row?

Tags: python, arrays, list, conditional-statements

I have a python 1D list that currently contains integers and then the letter `'t'`. 
For example:

```
list = [1,2,3,'t',2,3,2,'t',1,3,4,'t']
```

These integers actually signify the numbers 123, 232 and 134.
My solution needs to be an array with these numbers as integers and the 't' removed. So the new list would be 'a list (or numpy array) that inserts a new row every time a 't' is ran across and the integers before need to be stored in a row as 123, 232, 134.

Comment: Please post your code and the problem you have with it.  Stack Overflow is not intended as a homework service.

Comment: I have only included the relevant code. The code I posted is the only thing that is needed to describe the problem. If there is a link to documentation within stack overflow that deems my question as unsatisfactory, please point me to it. As I am trying to adhere to the principles of the community and site and understand that I may be ignorant to some standards, but felt my question and code relevancy was proper.

Comment: See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  You failed to post your attempt at soling the problem.

Comment: I appreciate your input.

Answer (score 3):

You can group the groups easily with [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). Then it's just a matter of covering the lists of ints to integers:

```
from itertools import groupby

l = [1,2,3,'t',2,3,2,'t',1,3,4,'t']

[int("".join(map(str, v))) for k, v in
 groupby(l, key=lambda x: x!='t') if k]

# [123, 232, 134]
```

It's helpful to understand what groupie is doing. If you take out the code that makes the ints from the groups you are left with:

```
[list(v) for k, v in groupby(l, key=lambda x: x!='t') if k]

# [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 2], [1, 3, 4]]
```

This just groups the list by whether or not the element equals 't'. `k` here will either by `True` or `False`. This filters out the `False` values with the `if k`.

The rest is just stitching the numbers together and making an integer:

```
"".join(map(str, v)))
```

The nice bit about using itertools is that it will gracefully handle large input — it deals with things as they come.

Comment: Perhaps you could also spend a few word explaining what you have done. Your code is both elegant and dense, and somebody learning the language may struggle a bit understanding it.

Comment: Awesome list comprehension, upvoted! I was still at `''.join([str(e) for e in list]).split('t')` when your posted. Also I think @norok2 was right

Comment: Thanks @norok2 — I've fleshed it out a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Simple method:

```
output = []
number = 0
for elem in list:
    if type(elem) == int:
        number = number * 10 + elem
    elif elem == 't':
        output.append(number)
        number = 0
    else:
        # Handle other cases
```

That being said, I'm not sure what you mean by "new row". Inserting elements in this way creates a 1D list.

Comment: This will not work  as `number` will keep on growing despite having been appended to `output`. You should add `number = 0` after the `.append()` line.

Comment: @norok2 Thanks, I've made the change.

Answer (score 0):

You can join the digits and `t`s together as a string, split it into number strings by the letter `t`, and convert each number string into an integer with `int` if it isn't empty (assuming the input list is stored as `l`):

```
[int(i) for i in ''.join(map(str, l)).split('t') if i]
```